# Scanner filling my array with 0

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

For my program I need to read from a dat file and store the 20 numbers in an array. However the only thing being stored in my array is 0. Is there something wrong with my scanner? I can compile the program fine. But when I print the array the only thing printed are 0's even though I clearly set them equal to the next int on the file. I've been staring at this program for a while and can't find the problem. Can someone tell me what is wrong.

Here is my program

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class DuplicateTesterAP
 {   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     //sets up scanner 
    Scanner inFile = null;
    try
    { 
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("prog415h.dat")); 
    }   
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    { 
        System.out.println("File not found!!"); 
        System.exit(0); 
    } 

    //creates array and declares variables
    int[] numbers = new int[20];
    int determine = 0;
    int space = 0;
```

I assume the error is here

```
    //stores values from file into array
    for(int i = 0 ; i<numbers.length; i++){
        numbers[i] = inFile.nextInt();
    }




    //creates a duplicateap object
    DuplicateAP object = new DuplicateAP(numbers);

    //finds the repeating numbers and stores them into an array
    object.findRepeat();

    //header
    System.out.println("The original set of numbers are: ");

    //output for original set of numbers 
    for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " " );
    }
```

Here is my dat file

```
12
12
30
12
45
66
78
30
82
19
99
11
11
15
31
18
51
17
12
17
```

Comment: If *that* code prints all 0's with *that* input file, then either `new DuplicateAP(numbers)` or `object.findRepeat()` clears the `numbers` array. Since we don't see that code, how would we know what is wrong?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ --- *"I assume the error is here"*??? Why assume when debugging will tell you for sure?

Comment: Just debug and check what is the value of each `inFile.nextInt();`

Comment: Try putting the for output right after the for input and test just that

Comment: @user3437460 How do I do that

Answer (score -1):

You have to check if the scanner's next token is a valid int value, so the loop would look like this:

```
int i = 0;
// stores values from file into array
while (inFile.hasNextInt()) {
    numbers[i++] = inFile.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: This can go off the end of the array if there are more than 20 numbers in the file.